# Counting points in Laravel's Eloquent or plain SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have two tables

visit:

```
|id | start | end | name | location | user_id
```

action:

```
|id | time | name | location | points
```

I need to select all of the visits and get sum of points for every action that has time bigger than start and lesser than end and also same name and location.

I wanted to add column "visit_id" but the project is already running and the system which logs everything is maintained by another company, so I have to join those probably.

Any idea how to approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT visit.id, SUM(action.points) FROM visit
JOIN action ON visit.name = action.name 
    AND visit.location = action.location
    AND visit.start <= action.time
    AND action.time < visit.end
GROUP BY visit.id
```